# Can a Ger be a Christian or another who worships any of Gd other than the Gd of the Torah?

Tags: gentiles, christianity

Christians will use Deuteronomy 10-18, and other verses with "ger" to say that they are also equal in Gd's love for his people. I was wondering if a Ger could apply to an idol worshiper, as Christians worship another Gd.

Comment: Those verses need to be read in context. “Ger” means foreigner, and it describes a non-Jew who resides in the Land of Israel, who has taken on the customs of the land (look up “ger toshav”). The original intention probably does not include just anyone, and probably does not mean a Jewish convert, as modern Jewish interpretations seem to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Ger literally means stranger/foreigner. In this case, it cannot mean idol worshippers, as the Jews were commanded in many places to uproot any and all idolatry and idolaters from their midst.

The verse you mentioned is only applied to converts to the Jewish faith.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious to a reader without a strong background in limmud Torah that a stranger/foreigner cannot be an idol worshipper. Some more explanation would be useful here

Comment: @יהושעק It's all spelled out very clearly in Devarim/Deuteronomy.

Comment: The original intention of the verse was not Jewish converts but rather gerei toshav

Comment: @N.T. I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm asking you to expand on your answer so that the OP or someone stumbling across this question in a web search can understand it.